# Como arrastar a Div para outra coluna?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

Na imagem Abaixo, tenho varias colunas onde o usuario pode arrastar a div e colocar em outra coluna, como ilustrado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) do *Jquery-UI*. Consigo arrastar esta div para a outra coluna sem maiores problemas com o código abaixo:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
```

Gostaria de persistir essa informação no banco de dados, ou seja, quando o usuario voltasse na página as `divs` estariam no lugar que ele deixou.

Alguém pode me ajudar em como fazer?

Comment: Atualizar o banco de dados para criar e alterar são ação é utilizar ajax, mas já existe baixar plugin tem q procurar "drag" e não lembro o nome certo.

Comment: isto chama-se drag and drop, consigo arrastar normalmente, porém, gostaria de quando arrastar, eu atualizar o banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi, se já fez drag and drop, use div + bind + onchange para trabalhar e ação fazer gravação, se puder posta seu código que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Eu postei todos, faltou algum ali?

Comment: Mas esta utilizado PHP? poste http://www.phpfiddle.org (Obs: sem tags php?)

Comment: Sim, eu não fiz a atualização do banco de dados, apenas a parte que arrasta os negocios pra div do lado... então, tudo que eu fiz, está aqui.

Comment: @AndréBaill é praticamente esse Fiddle, você só tem que adpatar. https://jsfiddle.net/k0owpLLx/